# Split List Into Groups of 3 with Flexbox with narrow gap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get a list into groups of 3.

I have something like

```css
.card {
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .details-container {
      flex: 1 1 60%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
  
      .items {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 20px;
        height: calc(100% * (1 / 3) - 10px - 1px);
          list-style: none;
      }
```

```html
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-container">
    </div>
    <div class="details-container">
      <div>Header</div>

      <ul class="items">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
        <li>item 6</li>
      </ul>
      <a class="view-all-details button is-primary">View All Details</a>
    </div>
```

This does work as I want but you will see a huge gap between lists. I tried "divs" as well but still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) to reduce the gap then adjust margin of flex items:

```css
.card {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.details-container {
  flex: 1 1 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content:center; /*OR flex-start if you want to align to the left*/
  margin: 20px;
  height: calc(100% * (1 / 3) - 10px - 1px);
  list-style: none;
}
.items > * {
  margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="img-container">
  </div>
  <div class="details-container">
    <div>Header</div>

    <ul class="items">
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
      <li>item 5</li>
      <li>item 6</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="view-all-details button is-primary">View All Details</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: In my real code, the 2 columns are very close to each other that they almost merge together as I think my text is alot longer then in this sample. Should I put on each "li" a margin-right or is there another way?

Comment: @chobo2 I don't think there is another way, we only have align properties (like align-content, justify-content,align-items) and margin in order to control distance